# How to call a method with an if else statement

Tags: java, methods

Just as the title says: I have a method that I need to call, but I'm not sure how. Here's the method:

```
public static int wordOrder(int order, String result1, String result2){
    order = result1.compareToIgnoreCase(result2);
    if (order == 0){
        System.out.println("The words are the same.");
    }else if (order > 0){
        System.out.println("The order of the words alphabetically is " +result2+ " then " +result1+ ".");
    }else{
        System.out.println("The order of the words alphabetically is " +result1+ " then " +result2+  ".");
    } 
    return order;
  }
```

How am I supposed to call that in the main method? Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason for you to keep `int order` as an argument to the method.

Comment: See [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this

main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       int resultFromMethod= wordOrder(2,"result1","result2");
    // your method accept argument as int, String , String and 
    // it is returning int value
    }
```

This is your method

```
    public static int wordOrder(int order, String result1, String result2){
        order = result1.compareToIgnoreCase(result2);
        if (order == 0){
            System.out.println("The words are the same.");
        }else if (order > 0){
            System.out.println("The order of the words alphabetically is " +result2+ " then " +result1+ ".");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The order of the words alphabetically is " +result1+ " then " +result2+  ".");
        }
        return order;
    }
```

This live [Demo](http://ideone.com/nRwTck) may help you.

Answer (score 2):

Like this: `wordOrder(1, "a", "b");` (the first parameter makes no sense, though).

Comment: How would I set the parameters?

Comment: By just *writing* them like in the given example.

Comment: @Salma The same as you call all other methods. `System.out.println(String s)` is a method, you know.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want only to call a method from the main method. The code could be like this

```
public static void main(String [] args){
   int myOrder = wordOrder(1, "One word", "Second word");
}

public static int wordOrder(int order, String result1, String result2){
    order = result1.compareToIgnoreCase(result2);
    if (order == 0){
        System.out.println("The words are the same.");
    }else if (order > 0){
        System.out.println("The order of the words alphabetically is " +result2+ " then " +result1+ ".");
    }else{
        System.out.println("The order of the words alphabetically is " +result1+ " then " +result2+  ".");
    } 
    return order;
  }
```

**As an extra note:** This can be done only if the method `wordOrder` is set as static, if not it will appear that **it can't  be referenced a non-static method from a static context.**

Answer (score 0):

qqilihq gave you correct answer but you can eliminate from function unused variables and make function:

```
public static int wordOrder(String result1, String result2){
  int order = result1.compareToIgnoreCase(result2);
  if (order == 0){
    System.out.println("The words are the same.");
  }else if (order > 0){
    System.out.println("The order of the words alphabetically is " +result2+ " then " +result1+ ".");
  }else{
    System.out.println("The order of the words alphabetically is " +result1+ " then " +result2+  ".");
  } 
  return order;
}
```

and call this function:

```
wordOrder("a","b");
```

Comment: @AndrewMartin No, he hasn't, he removed `int order` from the method signature.

Comment: additionaly I removed unnecessary argument from function ;)

Comment: Fair enough - apologies!